# Select N rows above and below match

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to select N rows above and below a match.

I'm trying the command:

```
mtcars[which(mtcars$vs == 1) + c(-1:1), ]
```

It returns the follow warning:

> Warning message:
>   In which(mtcars$vs == 1) + c(-1:1):
>   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: This should work for you `mtcars[which(mtcars$vs == 1)[1] + c(-1:1), ]`. Because `which` will return a series of matches (not the first one). By adding `[1]` you keep only the first match. You can also use `mtcars[min(which(mtcars$vs == 1)) + c(-1:1), ]` if you prefer. Similar logic... You can also input the number of rows you want like this `N = 1;
mtcars[min(which(mtcars$vs == 1)) + c(-N:N), ]`

Comment: Similarly to `mtcars[min(which(mtcars$vs == 1)) + c(-1:1), ]` provided by @AntoniosK , you can also use `mtcars[first(which(mtcars$vs == 1)) + c(-1:1), ]`.

Comment: @tmfmnk you need `dplyr` for `first`, right?

Comment: @AntoniosK you are right.

Comment: Another way might be, but it was reacently closed... `n <- 1` `i <- head(tail(filter(c(rep(FALSE, n), mtcars$vs == 1, rep(FALSE, n)), rep(1, 1+n*2)), -n), -n) > 0` `mtcars[i,]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a simple question but is not as trivial as presumably expected.

The issue is that `which(mtcars$vs == 1)` returns a vector rather than a single value:

> ```
> [1]  3  4  6  8  9 10 11 18 19 20 21 26 28 32
> ```

If another vector `-1:1` (which is `c(-1L, 0L, 1L)`) is added to it, the normal R rules for operations on vectors of unequal lengths apply: [The recycling rule](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule) says

> Any short vector operands are extended by recycling their values until
>   they match the size of any other operands.

Therefore the shorter vector `-1:1` will be recycled to the length of `which(mtcars$vs == 1)`, i.e.,

```
rep(-1:1, length.out = length(which(mtcars$vs == 1)))
```

> ```
>  [1] -1  0  1 -1  0  1 -1  0  1 -1  0  1 -1  0
> ```

Therefore, the result of

```
which(mtcars$vs == 1) + -1:1
```

is the *element-wise* sum of the elements of both vectors where the shorter vector has been recycled to match the length of the longer vector.

> ```
>  [1]  2  4  7  7  9 11 10 18 20 19 21 27 27 32
> ```

which is propably not what the OP has expected.

In addition, we get the

> Warning message:
>   In which(mtcars$vs == 1) + -1:1 :
>     longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

because `which(mtcars$vs == 1)` has length 14 and `-1:1` has length 3.

#### Solution using `outer()`

In order to select the `N` rows above and below *each* matching row, we need to add `-N:N` to *each* row number returned by `which(mtcars$vs == 1)`:

```
outer(which(mtcars$vs == 1), -1:1, `+`)

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    2    3    4
 [2,]    3    4    5
 [3,]    5    6    7
 [4,]    7    8    9
 [5,]    8    9   10
 [6,]    9   10   11
 [7,]   10   11   12
 [8,]   17   18   19
 [9,]   18   19   20
[10,]   19   20   21
[11,]   20   21   22
[12,]   25   26   27
[13,]   27   28   29
[14,]   31   32   33
```

Now, we have an array of all row numbers. Unfortunately, it cannot be used directly for subsetting because it contains duplicates and there are row numbers which do not exist in `mtcars`. So the the result has to be "post-processed" before it can be used for subsetting.

```
library(magrittr) # piping used for clarity
rn <- outer(which(mtcars$vs == 1), -1:1, `+`) %>% 
  as.vector() %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  Filter(function(x) x[1 <= x & x <= nrow(mtcars)], .)

rn
```

> ```
>  [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 17 18 19 20 21 22 25 26 27 28 29 31 32
> ```

```
mtcars[rn, ]
```

> ```
>                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
> Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
> Datsun 710        22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
> Valiant           18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
> Duster 360        14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
> Merc 240D         24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
> Merc 230          22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
> Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
> Merc 280C         17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
> Merc 450SE        16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
> Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
> Fiat 128          32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
> Honda Civic       30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
> Toyota Corolla    33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
> Toyota Corona     21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
> Dodge Challenger  15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
> Pontiac Firebird  19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
> Fiat X1-9         27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
> Porsche 914-2     26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
> Lotus Europa      30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
> Ford Pantera L    15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
> Maserati Bora     15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
> Volvo 142E        21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
> ```

Answer (score 3):

We can write a short function to return all elements of `vec` that match `val` or that are  within `n` elements (either direction):

```
newfun <- function(vec, val, n) {
    rows <- sapply(which(vec==val), function(x) seq(x-n, x+n, 1))
    rows <- unique(sort(rows[rows>0 & rows<length(vec)]))
    return(vec[rows])
}
```

For example:

```
newfun(mtcars$vs, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Before adding the desired range of indices to your focal index (the result from `which`), you need to repeat each value to the length of your range.

```
# set the number of values to select, before and after each focal index
n <- 1

# create a range of (relative) indices
i <- -n:n

# repeat focal indices 
# add range of n prior and following indices  
ix <- rep(which(mtcars$vs == 1), each = length(i)) + i

# select unique indices, truncated to the relevant range of rows,...
unique(ix[ix > 0 & ix <= nrow(mtcars)])
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 17 18 19 20 21 22 25 26 27 28 29 31 32

# ...which then can be used to subset data
mtcars[unique(ix[ix > 0 & ix <= nrow(mtcars)]), ]
```